# Property 'nextTick' does not exist on type when importing Vue3 in Jest test

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, ts-jest

I'm trying to import `nextTick` and a few other function from Vue3 in my Jest tests, but I see this error `Property 'nextTick' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/XXXXX/dev/XXXXX/src/XXXXX/packages/XXXXX/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")'.`

```
import * as vue from 'vue';
import useClassNames from './useClassNames';

describe('useClassNames', () => {
  it('render', async () => {
    const result = useClassNames([]);
    await vue.nextTick();
    expect(result).toBe([]);
  });
});
```

What's strange is that `nextTick` is there. `Object.keys(vue)` returns:

```
[
  'EffectScope',
  'ReactiveEffect',
  'customRef',
  'effect',
  'effectScope',
  'getCurrentScope',
  'isProxy',
  'isReactive',
  'isReadonly',
  'isRef',
  'isShallow',
  'markRaw',
  'onScopeDispose',
  'proxyRefs',
  'reactive',
  'readonly',
  'ref',
  'shallowReactive',
  'shallowReadonly',
  'shallowRef',
  'stop',
  'toRaw',
  'toRef',
  'toRefs',
  'triggerRef',
  'unref',
  'camelize',
  'capitalize',
  'normalizeClass',
  'normalizeProps',
  'normalizeStyle',
  'toDisplayString',
  'toHandlerKey',
  'BaseTransition',
  'Comment',
  'Fragment',
  'KeepAlive',
  'Static',
  'Suspense',
  'Teleport',
  'Text',
  'callWithAsyncErrorHandling',
  'callWithErrorHandling',
  'cloneVNode',
  'compatUtils',
  'computed',
  'createBlock',
  'createCommentVNode',
  'createElementBlock',
  'createElementVNode',
  'createHydrationRenderer',
  'createPropsRestProxy',
  'createRenderer',
  'createSlots',
  'createStaticVNode',
  'createTextVNode',
  'createVNode',
  'defineAsyncComponent',
  'defineComponent',
  'defineEmits',
  'defineExpose',
  'defineProps',
  'getCurrentInstance',
  'getTransitionRawChildren',
  'guardReactiveProps',
  'h',
  'handleError',
  'initCustomFormatter',
  'inject',
  'isMemoSame',
  'isRuntimeOnly',
  'isVNode',
  'mergeDefaults',
  'mergeProps',
  'nextTick', <-- here it is
  'onActivated',
  'onBeforeMount',
  'onBeforeUnmount',
  'onBeforeUpdate',
  'onDeactivated',
  'onErrorCaptured',
  'onMounted',
  'onRenderTracked',
  'onRenderTriggered',
  'onServerPrefetch',
  'onUnmounted',
  'onUpdated',
  'openBlock',
  'popScopeId',
  'provide',
  'pushScopeId',
  'queuePostFlushCb',
  'registerRuntimeCompiler',
  'renderList',
  'renderSlot',
  'resolveComponent',
  'resolveDirective',
  'resolveDynamicComponent',
  'resolveFilter',
  'resolveTransitionHooks',
  ... 44 more items
]
```

The same error happens when I try to import `h` and other functions.

`import vue from 'vue';` returns `undefined`.

`import { nextTick } from 'vue';` returns `src/hooks/useClassNames.spec.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'nextTick'.`

Installed dependencies

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test-with-coverage": "COLLECT_TEST_COVERAGE=TRUE jest",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.14.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/jest-axe": "^3.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "2.3.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "26.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.1.1",
    "jest": "~26.6.3",
    "jest-axe": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.52.2",
    "ts-jest": "~26.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.8",
    "vite": "^2.9.10",
    "vue-tsc": "0.37.0"
  }
}
```

Jest configuration

```
const collectCoverage = process.env.COLLECT_TEST_COVERAGE === 'TRUE';

module.exports = {
  // Test in browser like environment.
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['vue', 'ts', 'js'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue3-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  collectCoverage,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/{components,hooks}/**/*.{js,ts,vue}'],
  coverageReporters: ['html', 'text-summary'],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage',
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 80,
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
    },
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "jest.setup.ts",
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "include": [
    "vite.config.ts"
  ]
}
```